# Timer : clearInterval() doesn't work (js)

Tags: javascript

I don't understand this bug.

There is my simple code :

```
var refreshInterval;

function refreshAuto()
{
    if($("#refresh-select").val() == "off")
    {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        console.log("I'm here !");
    }
    else
    {
        refreshInterval = setInterval("console.log('bip')", $("#refresh-select").val());
    }
}
```

I select the timer with a drop-down list.
The code works excepted (timer's arguments are ok, I've tested) the part who I clear the interval. It's not clearing the Interval. The console tell me "I'm here" when I select "off", but doesn't stop to "bip". Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem with a jsFiddle?

Comment: You are creating a new interval whenever `refreshAuto` is called. `refreshInterval` will always only refer to the most recently created interval.  You should only create a single interval (e.g. outside of `refreshAuto `) or use `setTimeout`.

Comment: @FelixKling I see what u mean but I'm initializing refreshInverval outside the function, It's didn't enough?

Comment: Also, avoid passing a string to setInterval, pass a function instead

Comment: @AdrienWeidemann: If it was, it would work, wouldn't it ;) Think about it: Why are you creating a new interval even if one is already running?

Comment: Ok I just understood what u said before thx to @plbsam post. Ty dude, your comment was useful

Answer (score 2):

If you press the on button multiple times that could happen. The reason is even though the reference for a new interval replaces the first one, the first interval is not cleared then.

Try this,

```
var refreshInterval;

function refreshAuto()
{
    clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    if($("#refresh-select").val() == "off")
    {
        console.log("I'm here !");
    }
    else
    {
        refreshInterval = setInterval("console.log('bip')", $("#refresh-select").val());
    }
}
```

Comment: In that case you can move `clearInterval(refreshInterval);` outside the `if...else`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to remedy this is to only schedule the timer if you don't already have it running:

```
var refreshInterval;

function refreshAuto() {
    var refreshSelection = $("#refresh-select").val();

    if(refreshSelection === "off") {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        refreshInterval = null;
        console.log("I'm here !");
    }
    else if (!refreshInterval) {
        refreshInterval = setInterval(function() { console.log('bip'); }, 
                                      refreshSelection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Each time you create an interval, it creates a timeout, you do not overwrite the last one just because it is named. If you would have console.log out a different value you would have seen that.

```
var refreshInterval;

function refreshAuto()
{
    if($("#refresh-select").val() == "off")
    {
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);
        console.log("I'm here !");
    }
    else
    {
        var interval = $("#refresh-select").val()
        refreshInterval = setInterval( function() { console.log('bip', interval ); } , interval );
    }
}
```

Now when you run it your log will show the issue when you change the intervals two times with a one second and 5 second delay.

```
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 5000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 1000
bip 5000
```

---

**One Solution**

To get around the issue, you can clear the interval every time you set it.

```js
    var refreshInterval;

    function refreshAuto() {
      if (refreshInterval) window.clearInterval(refreshInterval);
      var val = $("#refresh-select").val();
      if (val !== "off") {
        refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log('bip', val);
        }, parseFloat(val));
      }
    }

    $("#refresh-select").on("change", refreshAuto).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="refresh-select">
  <option value="off">Off</option>
  <option value="1000">1</option>
  <option value="5000">5</option>
  <option value="30000">30</option>
  <option value="60000">60
    <option>
</select>
```

Comment: (Yes I know I am late - stopped to get coffee in the middle of answering)